# Translation and remove action with if else statement

Tags: r, function, recode

So I am working on a dataset which has a column with a lot of different values. To give you an idea I have created below sample. I would like to add some sort of function in order to skip a lot of manual work.

A small example:

```
Species = c(
    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa",
    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
    "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", 
    "setosa", "setosa", "versicolor", "versicolor",
    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor",
    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor",
    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor",
    "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor", "versicolor",
    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica",
    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica",
    "virginica", "virginica", "virginica", "virginica"
```

So with the above dataset I would like to rename the values. The values that are not mentioned should be changed to but to an empty value like "". (see below for example)

```
library(dplyr)

translate <- function(x) {
 x %>% recode(
   "setosa" = "good",
   "verginica" = "bad"
   "versicolor" = "")

translate(Species)
```

I am wondering if there is an option to change the last one "versicolor" = "" to some sort of `else` statement where all other values (so not only versicolor) will be changed to an empte value like ""

Answer (score 0):

You may consider simply adding a new column in the dataset. For example,

```
# for values that are not mentioned
data$Species1 <- ""

# for values that are mentioned
data$Species1[which(data$Species == "setosa")] <- "good"
data$Species1[which(data$Species == "verginica")] <- "bad"
```

You may keep Species1 in the dataset, or replace it with Species and then delete Species1.

```
data$Species <- data$Species1
```